# Create a table using set of variables with values in R

Tags: r

I am sorry for editing the question. I realized I asked wrong question after first two replies.

```
Apple<-5
Banana<-10
```

How can you create a table like this below? I want to use variables only. I do not wish to type values because it is subjected to change.

```
Fruit How_Many
1 Apple   5
2 Banana  10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data.frame(Fruit = c('Apple', 'Banana'), How_many = c(Apple, Banana))
#   Fruit How_many
#1  Apple        5
#2 Banana       10
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This was what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
rm(list = ls())
Apple = 5
Banana = 10
Watermelon = 15
Mango = 16
Pineapple = 18

setNames(stack(mget(ls())), c("How_many", "Fruit"))[2:1]
#        Fruit How_many
# 1      Apple        5
# 2     Banana       10
# 3      Mango       16
# 4  Pineapple       18
# 5 Watermelon       15
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I posted wrong question originally, but I wanted to thank you as well.